# Deploy Android ASP.Net Application on IIS 5.1 on Windows XP

Tags: android, asp.net, iis, windows-xp

**Server Error in '/TabletA' Application.**

**Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: site**

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: site

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: site]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +238

[HttpException (0x80004005): Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: site]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +8946484
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +258

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

Comment: Please be descriptive when you ask a question. Looking at your output, you are trying to access a parameter 'site' which is not in the parameter list.

Comment: Hi, I have deployed ASP.Net Web Services on IIS 5.1 running on Windows XP. The same code is working fine with IIS 7 running on Windows 7 using .Net Framework 4.0 . I need help to understand what is difference in deployment on Windows XP and Windows 7.